# Rename Bootstrap Tab with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up a system to create new tabs dynamically using jQuery, so that when a link is clicked it creates a new tab. The content of each tab is set as a textbox. Is it possible to change the title of the tab to what is entered into the text box, ideally as they type and not after having to click enter or another button?

I also have another problem, I'm not sure if this needs a new question or not but here goes anyway. I need to be able to also delete tabs, ideally when clicking a link. I gather that this is possible but I'm not sure quite how. So far I have thought of a jQuery function where you pass the id of the tab to it and it deletes the link and the content but I don't really know how to code it?

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/eYePA/

```
Info:
I am using Twitter Bootstrap with the theme Simplex from Bootswatch.
The CSS and JS files for Bootstrap are loaded from BootstrapCDN.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#tabContent').on('keyup', 'input[id^="pageTitle_tab"]', function(){
    var index  = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').index();
    $('#tabHeaders li:eq(' + (index + 1) + ') a').html(this.value)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ysS2z/)

Comment: Could you show me how this could integrate? Perhaps by adding a revision to my jsFiddle or providing an example? Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: @BenedictLewis I've the posted a fiddle in my answer

Comment: @BenedictLewis it is a working sample, you add a new tab and try editing the textfield

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I just realised you had done and it works perfectly! Thanks so much :)

Comment: If you need also 'delete tab' function workiing here is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ysS2z/2/ , gl!