# Change title of bootstrap Tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using bootstrap creating tabs How can I change the heading of the tabs? Snippet of tabs declaration:

```html
<div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul id="mainTabs"  class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li><a href="#respond" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Processing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#review" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Maintenance  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details  </a></li>
                
           </ul>
      </div>
```

`
On the tab maintenance I have a grid of orders. When I click an order # I want to change the heading/title of the details tab to "Order 123 Details" and then I will switch to that tab with the extended details. How can I change the title/heading of a bootstrap tab?

Comment: The answer is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880053/rename-bootstrap-tab-with-jquery) but I dont understand how to apply it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul id="mainTabs"  class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li><a href="#respond" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Processing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#review" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Maintenance  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details  </a></li>
                
           </ul>
      </div>
```